# Attempting to update duplicate fields to null where date is min and date is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to update the license_no field to null **if** the license_no is duplicated **and** has the oldest termination_date **and** if that termination_date is not null. The SQL query below is what I have so far. How can I determine the min termination_date for the duplicates in the update statement?

```
update driver
set license_no = NULL
where license_no IN (SELECT license_no 
                      FROM   driver 
                      GROUP  BY license_no 
                      HAVING ( Count(license_no) > 1 ))
```

Comment: If there are two rows with the same license number, where one of these rows has non-null date and second row has null date. Do you want to set license numbers to NULL in this case? Which one of the two?

Comment: If there are two rows with the same license number, where one of the rows has a non-null date and the second has a null date, I would want to update the license_no to null in the non-null record.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window function`. Try this.

```
UPDATE A
SET    license_no = NULL
FROM   driver A
       JOIN (SELECT Min(termination_date) termination_date,
                    license_no
             FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY license_no ORDER BY termination_date desc) rn,
                            *
                     FROM  driver) o
             WHERE  rn > 1
             GROUP  BY license_no) B
         ON a.license_no = b.license_no
            AND a.termination_date = b.termination_date
```

Comment: If there are two rows with the same license number, where one of these rows has non-null date and second row has null date, your solution would not update these rows at all, even though there are two licenses with the same number. It is not really clear from the question, whether this is the desired behavior, but my understanding is that one of these license should be updated (the one that has non-null date).

Answer (score 0):

I will use a table variable to have some sample data. I'll add various combinations of license numbers and dates to capture all possibilities.

Also, I will add and use an ID column to your schema. I my solution I need to identify each row separately. It is not enough to identify rows just by license number.

```
DECLARE @TDrivers TABLE (ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, license_no varchar(50) NULL, termination_date date NULL);

insert into @TDrivers values (1, NULL, '20130101');
insert into @TDrivers values (2, NULL, '20130101');
insert into @TDrivers values (3, NULL, '20130102');
insert into @TDrivers values (4, NULL, '20130103');
insert into @TDrivers values (5, NULL, '20130104');

-- only one license with this number
insert into @TDrivers values (6, '01', '20140101');

-- only one license with this number
insert into @TDrivers values (7, '02', NULL);

-- two licenses with this number, different dates
insert into @TDrivers values (8, '03', '20140301');
insert into @TDrivers values (9, '03', '20140302');

-- two licenses with this number, same dates
insert into @TDrivers values (10, '04', '20140401');
insert into @TDrivers values (11, '04', '20140401');

-- two licenses with this number, dates are not null and null
insert into @TDrivers values (12, '05', '20140501');
insert into @TDrivers values (13, '05', NULL);

-- two licenses with this number, both dates are null
insert into @TDrivers values (14, '06', NULL);
insert into @TDrivers values (15, '06', NULL);

-- three licenses with this number, dates are unique and not null
insert into @TDrivers values (16, '07', '20140701');
insert into @TDrivers values (17, '07', '20140702');
insert into @TDrivers values (18, '07', '20140703');

-- three licenses with this number, dates are not unique and not null
insert into @TDrivers values (19, '08', '20140801');
insert into @TDrivers values (20, '08', '20140801');
insert into @TDrivers values (21, '08', '20140802');

-- dates are unique and have one null
insert into @TDrivers values (22, '09', '20140901');
insert into @TDrivers values (23, '09', '20140902');
insert into @TDrivers values (24, '09', '20140903');
insert into @TDrivers values (25, '09', NULL);

-- dates are unique and have several nulls
insert into @TDrivers values (26, '10', '20141001');
insert into @TDrivers values (27, '10', '20141002');
insert into @TDrivers values (28, '10', '20141003');
insert into @TDrivers values (29, '10', NULL);
insert into @TDrivers values (30, '10', NULL);
insert into @TDrivers values (31, '10', NULL);

-- dates are not unique and have one null
insert into @TDrivers values (32, '11', '20141101');
insert into @TDrivers values (33, '11', '20141101');
insert into @TDrivers values (34, '11', '20141102');
insert into @TDrivers values (35, '11', '20141103');
insert into @TDrivers values (36, '11', NULL);

-- dates are not unique and have several nulls
insert into @TDrivers values (37, '12', '20141201');
insert into @TDrivers values (38, '12', '20141201');
insert into @TDrivers values (39, '12', '20141202');
insert into @TDrivers values (40, '12', '20141203');
insert into @TDrivers values (41, '12', NULL);
insert into @TDrivers values (42, '12', NULL);
insert into @TDrivers values (43, '12', NULL);

SELECT * FROM @TDrivers ORDER BY ID;
```

At first we'll find all license numbers that appear more than once:

```
WITH
CTE_DuplicatedLicenses
AS
(
    SELECT license_no
    FROM @TDrivers AS d
    WHERE license_no IS NOT NULL
    -- there is no need to update license numbers that are NULL already
    GROUP BY license_no
    HAVING (COUNT(license_no) > 1)
)
```

Then for each duplicated license number we are looking for one row that has a minimum termination date, which is not `NULL`. To resolve ambiguity when there are several rows with the same termination date I use `ID` column in the `ORDER BY`.

```
,CTE_LicensesWithDates
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Dates.ID
    FROM
        CTE_DuplicatedLicenses
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP (1) d.ID
            FROM @TDrivers AS d
            WHERE
                d.license_no = CTE_DuplicatedLicenses.license_no
                AND d.termination_date IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY
                d.termination_date, d.ID
        ) AS CTE_Dates
)
```

The last CTE gives us all `IDs` that should be updated:

```
update @TDrivers
set license_no = NULL
where ID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM CTE_LicensesWithDates
);

SELECT * FROM @TDrivers ORDER BY ID;
```

This is the original table:

```
ID   license_no   termination_date
1    NULL         2013-01-01
2    NULL         2013-01-01
3    NULL         2013-01-02
4    NULL         2013-01-03
5    NULL         2013-01-04
6    01           2014-01-01
7    02           NULL
8    03           2014-03-01
9    03           2014-03-02
10   04           2014-04-01
11   04           2014-04-01
12   05           2014-05-01
13   05           NULL
14   06           NULL
15   06           NULL
16   07           2014-07-01
17   07           2014-07-02
18   07           2014-07-03
19   08           2014-08-01
20   08           2014-08-01
21   08           2014-08-02
22   09           2014-09-01
23   09           2014-09-02
24   09           2014-09-03
25   09           NULL
26   10           2014-10-01
27   10           2014-10-02
28   10           2014-10-03
29   10           NULL
30   10           NULL
31   10           NULL
32   11           2014-11-01
33   11           2014-11-01
34   11           2014-11-02
35   11           2014-11-03
36   11           NULL
37   12           2014-12-01
38   12           2014-12-01
39   12           2014-12-02
40   12           2014-12-03
41   12           NULL
42   12           NULL
43   12           NULL
```

This is the updated table:

```
ID   license_no   termination_date
1    NULL         2013-01-01
2    NULL         2013-01-01
3    NULL         2013-01-02
4    NULL         2013-01-03
5    NULL         2013-01-04
6    01           2014-01-01
7    02           NULL
8    NULL         2014-03-01
9    03           2014-03-02
10   NULL         2014-04-01
11   04           2014-04-01
12   NULL         2014-05-01
13   05           NULL
14   06           NULL
15   06           NULL
16   NULL         2014-07-01
17   07           2014-07-02
18   07           2014-07-03
19   NULL         2014-08-01
20   08           2014-08-01
21   08           2014-08-02
22   NULL         2014-09-01
23   09           2014-09-02
24   09           2014-09-03
25   09           NULL
26   NULL         2014-10-01
27   10           2014-10-02
28   10           2014-10-03
29   10           NULL
30   10           NULL
31   10           NULL
32   NULL         2014-11-01
33   11           2014-11-01
34   11           2014-11-02
35   11           2014-11-03
36   11           NULL
37   NULL         2014-12-01
38   12           2014-12-01
39   12           2014-12-02
40   12           2014-12-03
41   12           NULL
42   12           NULL
43   12           NULL
```

To run this example just put all code blocks together in one script.

You can see in the result that rows with IDs 8, 10, 12 were updated.

Rows with IDs 14, 15 were not updated, because they both had NULL date.

For each other license number you can see that only one row was set to NULL, even if several rows had the same date.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I had to execute the update multiple times to catch all of the duplicates but this works! I appreciate your help and thorough explanation.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful for you. You can mark the answer as useful or accepted to help other people who may find this question later.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with some standard SQL like this:

```
UPDATE
  driver d
SET
  license_no = null
WHERE 
  Exists ( SELECT 
             d2.license_no 
           FROM 
             driver d2 
           WHERE 
             d2.license_no = d.license_no 
           GROUP BY 
             d2.license_no 
           HAVING 
             Count(d2.license_no) > 1 
         ) AND
  Exists ( SELECT 
             d3.license_no
           FROM 
             driver d3
           WHERE 
             d3.license_no = d.license_no AND
             d3.termination_date = d.termination_date AND 
             d3.termination_date IS NOT NULL AND
             d3.termination_date IN ( SELECT 
                                        Min(d4.termination_date) 
                                      FROM 
                                        driver d4 
                                      WHERE 
                                         d4.license_no = d.license_no )                            
         )
```

The first `Exists()` function checks for the duplicates.

The second `Exists()` function checks for the termination_date constraint.

Hope it helps!